# Can we make secure session using liferay-mobile-sdk in Android?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

If I open a session using Liferay Mobile Android SDK, username and password are send as plain text to the server. Any way to send them with encryption?

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPS for communication with your Liferay server.

Liferay is responsible for storing passwords with encryption (or better as salted hash) in the database. It is your responsibility to attach transport layer security to the login.